# Does Verilog allow Unicode characters in string literals?

Tags: unicode, verilog, system-verilog

I have a customer with a Verilog 2012 file (that he implicitly claims is valid) that contains a literal string that contains a non-ASCII character (the file is Unicode).

Here is an extract of the text:

```
  case(field_name)
    ...
    "afe_cmn_clkgen_reg2[cmn_sris_ena_nt]" : begin descr = "Enables SRIS generation in CMN.\n0 – SRIS generation disabled\n1 – SRIS generation enabled"; found = 1; end
    ...
```

The "dash" following "CMN.\n0" is actually Unicode hex #2013 (EM Dash).

The Verilog reference manuals insist that string literal content is "ASCII Characters".   This text is taken from section A.8.8 of the Verilog 2012 standard document:

**Strings string_literal ::= " { Any_ASCII_Characters } "**

I can't find anything else (on the Web) that discusses how Unicode is used with Verilog.

Can anybody find chapter and verse documentation of Unicode in Verilog?

Is it the case that some Verilog tools will read Unicode source files?  What do they do with non-ASCII characters? (A few answers found in SO seem to imply they choke on the non-ASCII characters).

Answer (score 0):

From IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 5.9 *String literals*:

> A string literal is a sequence of characters enclosed by double quotes
> ( "" ).
>
> Nonprinting and other special characters are preceded with a
> backslash.

Your code includes a nonprinting character (`\n`).

The Std does not mention "unicode" anywhere.  While this section does mention ASCII characters, it does not insist that a string literal must consist of only ASCII.

The same section states:

> String literals used as operands in expressions and assignments shall
> be treated as unsigned integer constants represented by a sequence of
> 8-bit ASCII values, with one 8-bit ASCII value representing one
> character.

If you display the variable, the output can vary from simulator to simulator.  I ran this code on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Xmd6), and I got varying results:

```
module tb;
  string descr;
  initial begin
    descr = "Enables SRIS generation in CMN.\n0 – SRIS generation disabled\n1 – SRIS generation enabled";
    $display(descr);
  end
endmodule
```

Cadence produced this output:

```
Enables SRIS generation in CMN.
0 ? SRIS generation disabled
1 ? SRIS generation enabled
```

Aldec produced this:

```
# KERNEL: Enables SRIS generation in CMN.
# KERNEL: 0 â€“ SRIS generation disabled
# KERNEL: 1 â€“ SRIS generation enabled
```

All the simulators there allow the character.  What you see probably also depends on your OS.  This character is legal (in the sense that the code compiles without error), but I recommend avoiding it.